# How to load a specific page after closing a window in Javascript

Tags: javascript, popup, location, reload

I've done this before but cannot recall how I did it! So not sure what to search for in my code!

Normally I close a pop up and reload the screen underneath.  Simple.

```
opener.location.reload();
self.close();
```

But instead of causing the underlying screen to reload, I want a specific url to load. 
What have I forgotten?

Comment: `parent.location = "myurl.com"`?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018567/loading-another-html-page-from-javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
opener.location = url;  // url being the url string
```

[See reference on `window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location)

Comment: Wow, I looked through a gazzilion lines of code and couldn't find that!  Must have used a different way but this works fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
opener.location = 'http://example.com';
self.close();
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation? This showed up in the LQP queue.